# Ext.ComboBox option selecting

Tags: extjs

**ExtJS 4.1**

I have `Ext.ComboBox` and a store bound to it.

How can I simulate `selection` of one of it's options from code so to `select` event would be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select option use `combo.select(1); combo.fireEvent('select', combo);`